# Layout margin apparently not working on smaller devices

Tags: android

Please have a look at these pictures.

As you can see **there is no margin in the smaller one !!!**

Please what am I doing wrong???

[image]

[image]

Here is a piece of the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/general_layout_margin"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

other widgets...
```

I have defined  the dimension `general_layout_margin` in `res/values/dimens.xml`

I have another `dimens.xml` in `res/values-w820dp` BUT I HAVEN'T DEFINED IT THERE.

Please what am I dong wrong???

Thanks!

```
<resources>
<dimen name="general_layout_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: its beacuse of this line ndroid:gravity="center_vertical" cause it take layout layout to center verticle thats y remove this and check again

Comment: @LazyCoder Hi lazy, no I have just tried, that seems not to be the cause

Comment: than also define that value in defult dimen.xml

Comment: @LazyCoder lazy wouldn't `res/values/dimens.xml` be the default?

Comment: can you snap that to show

Comment: Did you try defining the same in the other dimens file?

Comment: @codePG Hi code, yes I have just tried, no success :-(((

Comment: @LazyCoder Hi Lazy, screenshot added

Comment: have you adde d value in all dimen.xml?

Comment: What is values-small? Try making a duplicate of dimens.xml from values to values-small

Comment: Added the same value everywhere, same result :-((((

Comment: If values-small is not an important folder try deleting that folder from the project. The error could be because the android couldnt find dimens value in values-small and assumes that to 0dp. If any folder (example layout-small), the android will take that layouts as default for smaller screens (ldpi).

Comment: Have you tried putting the `android:layout_margin="@dimen/general_layout_margin"` into the inner, vertical layout? Just guessing around has helped me through a lot of layouting issues.

Comment: @codePG tried that, no success :-((

Comment: Another workaround could be to set the layout margin in your layout  itself (rather than using @dimens) to see if that works. If that too doesn't work, then the possible chances are that the problem is in the layout. Still if you couldn't figure out, kindly post the full xml of the layout.

Comment: @random6174 Random you did the trick!!! Thanks!!! (it is very strange though...) anyway if you want to post an answer I will happily accept and upvote it! Cheers. LISA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `android:layout_margin="@dimen/general_layout_margin"` into the inner, vertical layout.

It works and I have still no clue why. Welcome to layouting in Android.